# Accessing list and adding them total, python solution

Tags: python, list, input

The canteen in the Institute maintains has a table of prices of items, like:

- Samosa: 15
- Idli: 30
- Maggie: 50
- Dosa, 70
- …

For the program you have to write, set the menu in your program by this statement (feel free to add more items).

```
menu = [("Samosa", 15), ("Idli", 30), ("Maggie", 50), ("Dosa", 70), ("Tea", 10), ("Coffee", 20), ("Sandwich", 35), ("ColdDrink", 25)]
```

Write a program to take a user's order on a terminal and compute the bill. First show the menu by printing the menu. For ordering an item, the user inputs the item number and the quantity desired (e.g. an input can be: `3 1` followed by `1 5`). The program should prompt the user to order more, till he/she hits return (without any numbers) - which is the end of the order. Print a bill for this order in the form (for the input example above):

```
Maggie, 1, Rs 50
Samosa, 5, Rs 75

TOTAL, 6 items, Rs 125
```

How can I access the list and take inputs and add them?

Comment: Why did you specify the "[tag:answer-set-programming]" tag? I removed it since this is not ASP.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize the global variables:

```py
bill = []
total_quantity = 0
total_price = 0
```

Inside the loop you will ask for the order and exit the loop if it is an empty string:

```py
order = input("Please specify an item number and a quantity: ")
if order == "" : break
```

Then parse the order, by splitting the input string before and after the space:

```py
(index_string, quantity_string) = order.split(" ")
```

Now access the `menu` variable and compute the price:

```py
quantity = int(quantity_string)
item = menu[int(index_string)-1]
name = item[0]
unit_price = int(item[1])
price = unit_price * quantity
```

and update the global variables:

```py
bill.append("%s, %d, Rs %d" % (name, quantity, price))
total_quantity += quantity
total_price += price
```

Finally you can print what you collected:

```py
for string in bill :
    print(string)

print("\nTOTAL, %d items, Rs %d" % (total_quantity, total_price))
```

This is the final code:

```py
menu = [("Samosa", 15), ("Idli", 30), ("Maggie", 50), ("Dosa", 70), ("Tea", 10), ("Coffee", 20), ("Sandwich", 35), ("ColdDrink", 25)]
print(menu)

bill = []
total_quantity = 0
total_price = 0
while True :
    order = input("Please specify an item number and a quantity: ")
    if order == "" : break
    (index_string, quantity_string) = order.split(" ")
    quantity = int(quantity_string)
    item = menu[int(index_string)-1]
    name = item[0]
    unit_price = int(item[1])
    price = unit_price * quantity
    bill.append("%s, %d, Rs %d" % (name, quantity, price))
    total_quantity += quantity
    total_price += price

for string in bill :
    print(string)

print("\nTOTAL, %d items, Rs %d" % (total_quantity, total_price))
```